# Limiting Physicians to defined patients within a FHIR structure

Tags: hl7-fhir

Hospitals and clinic usually have a regional organizational structure and physicians are assigned to one of these levels --such as Region> to Market> to Clinics> and 1 or more patient data assigned to the clinic.

What is the most appropriate way to define this organizational structure with FHIR to ensure only physicians in their defined clinics can see their assigned patient data?

Comment: Some combination of these resources: 
http://build.fhir.org/practitioner.html
http://build.fhir.org/practitionerrole.html
http://build.fhir.org/location.html
http://build.fhir.org/organization.html

The business logic will be complex and no doubt very specific to each health system.

Comment: Also consider the Consent resource as a way to define access constraints